# Null Check to avoid Null pointer exception

Tags: java, null

I have something like this:

```
   request.getData().getPerson().getAddress().getZipcode()
```

I am looking for efficient way to do the null check but don't want to add many if's . I have similar thing in many places and looking for the best way to address this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `request.getData().getPerson().getAddress().getZipcode()` is a code smell in and of itself.

Comment: Please see message chains in code smell and also Law of Demeter for programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

```
Optional.ofNullable(request).map(x -> x.getData()).map(x -> x.getPerson())
        .map(x -> x.getAddress()).map(x -> x.getZipcode()).orElse(null);
```

Comment: @user16320675 I would have used those if I knew the names of the classes.

Comment: That looks like a good approach.